# How to add dynamically items to the table in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Do someone know how to add dynamically more rows into the DataTable in Flutter. As you can see my code is very 'hardcoded' [line: 11-31].
There should be a way to get rid of writing more and more DataRows.

Code:

```
class DataTableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text('Patch')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Version')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Ready')),
      ],
      rows: <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('AAAAAA')),
            DataCell(Text('1')),
            DataCell(Text('Yes')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('BBBBBB')),
            DataCell(Text('2')),
            DataCell(Text('No')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('CCCCCC')),
            DataCell(Text('3')),
            DataCell(Text('Yes')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

You can use

```
listOfColumns.map(((element) => DataRow(...))).toList()
```

This is your code using this method.

```
class DataTableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, String>> listOfColumns = [
    {"Name": "AAAAAA", "Number": "1", "State": "Yes"},
    {"Name": "BBBBBB", "Number": "2", "State": "no"},
    {"Name": "CCCCCC", "Number": "3", "State": "Yes"}
  ];
//  DataTableWidget(this.listOfColumns);     // Getting the data from outside, on initialization
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text('Patch')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Version')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Ready')),
      ],
      rows:
          listOfColumns // Loops through dataColumnText, each iteration assigning the value to element
              .map(
                ((element) => DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(Text(element["Name"])), //Extracting from Map element the value
                        DataCell(Text(element["Number"])),
                        DataCell(Text(element["State"])),
                      ],
                    )),
              )
              .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not what I want. I just want to enter the size of the table (row and column) and get a datatable oder table. there should be a common way for it.

Answer (score 14):

You could do something like this:**

```
class DataTableWidget extends StatelessWidget {

      List results=[] ;
       intState((){
         super.iniState();
            this.getSale();
 })
Future<String> getData () async {

var response = await http.get(
  "$saleUrl/?format=json",

);
setState(() {
  var dataConvertedToJson = 
json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
  results = dataConvertedToJson['results'];
});
 print('${results.length}');
  return "successful";
 }
  DataRow _getDataRow(result) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(data["text1"])),
        DataCell(Text(data["text2"])),
        DataCell(Text(data["text3"])),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text('Patch')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Version')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Ready')),
      ],
      rows: List.generate(
          results.length, (index) => _getDataRow(results[index])),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why is the list empty? The code does not show text1, text2 and text3

Comment: @SarahPöhler I left the list empty, because I don't know if you are getting the data from a server or local database or something else. Populating the list is not the point of this question. But since you don't seem satisfied, I edited my answer

Answer (score 5):

The underlying data structure, probably a list, is what you want to worry about changing.  UI elements like the table just observe.  The setState() function notifies the UI to take a fresh look after you've updated your list.

Here's a working example hacked from a flutter doc example.  Click the button to add rows.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Add Rows',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Add Rows'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DataRow> _rowList = [
    DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Text('AAAAAA')),
      DataCell(Text('1')),
      DataCell(Text('Yes')),
    ]),
  ];

  void _addRow() {
    // Built in Flutter Method.
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below.
      _rowList.add(DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text('BBBBBB')),
        DataCell(Text('2')),
        DataCell(Text('No')),
      ]));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DataTable(columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Text('Patch')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('Version')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('Ready')),
        ], rows: _rowList),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _addRow,
        label: Text('Add Row'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This builds for me with

```
flutter build web
```

then run with

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Comment: setState() was exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this,
In a column, I've added an add item button, which will add another row to the table every time you click on it. Add the below code in a column.

```
MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          details.add({
            "Name": "",
            "Maths": "",
            "Science": "",
            "Total": "",
          });
        });
      },
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: const Text("Add Item"),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 10,),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            final rowHeight = (constraints.maxHeight - 40) / details.length;
            return DataTable(
                dataRowMaxHeight: rowHeight,
                dataRowMinHeight: 35,
                headingRowHeight: 30,
                headingRowColor:  MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.blue[50]),
                columns: const [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Maths')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Science')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Total')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('')),
                ],
                rows: List.generate(details.length, (index) {
                  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
                  TextEditingController mathsController = TextEditingController();
                  TextEditingController scienceController = TextEditingController();
                  TextEditingController totalController = TextEditingController();
                  nameController.text = details[index]['Name']!;
                  mathsController.text = details[index]['Maths']!;
                  scienceController.text = details[index]['Science']!;
                  nameController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: nameController.text.length));
                  mathsController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: mathsController.text.length));
                  scienceController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: scienceController.text.length));
                  return DataRow(
                      cells: [
                        DataCell(
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 200,
                                height: 50,
                                color: Colors.blue[50],
                                child: const TextField(
                                  // expands: true,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.blue[50],
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: 50,
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: mathsController,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 3, right: 3)
                                    ),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      try{
                                        double maths = double.parse(value);
                                        setState(() {
                                          details[index]['Maths'] = maths.toString();
                                          double science = double.tryParse(details[index]['Science'] ?? "")?? 0;
                                          details[index]['Total'] = (maths + science).toString();
                                        });
                                      }catch(e){
                                        print("Invalid input for Maths: $value");
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.blue[50],
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: 50,
                                  child: TextField(
                                    controller: scienceController,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 3, right: 3)
                                    ),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      try {
                                        double science = double.parse(value);
                                        setState(() {
                                          details[index]["Science"] = science.toString();
                                          double maths = double.tryParse(details[index]['Maths'] ?? '') ?? 0;
                                          details[index]['Total'] = (maths + science).toString();
                                        });
                                      } catch (e) {
                                        print("Invalid input for Science: $value");
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.blue[50],
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: 50,
                                  child: TextField(
                                    readOnly: true,
                                    controller: TextEditingController(text: details[index]['Total']),
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 3, right: 3)
                                    ),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      details[index]["Total"] = value;
                                      totalController.text = value;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                            ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {

                                }, child: const Text("Edit"))
                        )
                      ]
                  );
                })
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

This is the list where I'm rendering data from.

```
List<Map<String, String>> details = [{
"Name": "Rahul",
"Maths": "80",
"Science": "70",
"Total": "150",},{
"Name": "Babu",
"Maths": "50",
"Science": "50",
"Total": "100",},];
```